# MongoDB aggregate array documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a MongoDB collection containing elements like this:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "instances": [
        {
            "year": 2015
        },
        {
            "year": 2016
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I get the minimum and maximum value for `year` within the document named `test`? E.g. I want to aggregate all documents inside that array, but I can't find the syntax for that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: umm, yeah, you're probably right. I'll update that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html) and [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/index.html) takes an array as a parameter and in your case path `instances.year` returns an array so your query can look like below:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { name: "test" }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            minYear: { $min: "$instances.year" },
            maxYear: { $max: "$instances.year" }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "maxYear": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$instances",
        {
          "$indexOfArray": [
            "$instances.year",
            { "$max": "$instances.year" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "minYear": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$instances",
        {
          "$indexOfArray": [
            "$instances.year",
            { "$min": "$instances.year" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```